# Adb error "Connection with adb was interrupted."

Tags: android, adb

It is the first time I use eclipse in win 8.1 but I have the same problem in win 7. First I installed jdk 7 and then sdk 22 and then extracted adt v 20 and new when I open eclipse:

```
    [2014-03-26 03:24:46 - ddms] Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: 
Unable to establish loopback connection
```

and when I want to run a hello world app I face This problem:

```
[2014-03-26 03:10:26 - Hi] Android Launch!
[2014-03-26 03:10:26 - Hi] Connection with adb was interrupted.
[2014-03-26 03:10:26 - Hi] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect.
[2014-03-26 03:10:26 - Hi] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.
```

I reset adb from devices console but no result found!

Comment: Try killing the adb server and start it again with the help of terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill adb server from command prompt using:

```
  adb kill-server
```

and then restart using:

```
  adb start-server
```

Also try restarting eclipse. 
I faced the same problem, tried all these, and finally resolved on System restart.

Comment: 1) Go to the folder where your Android SDK is located. 2) Go to Platform tools. 3) You will now be able to see 'adb' inside that, now press shift + right click, and choose 'Open command prompt here'. 4) Then type the above mentioned commands.